# What's the quickest way to find duplicated files?

Tags: centos, files, find, duplicate-files

I found this command used to find duplicated files but it was quite long and made me confused.

For example, if I remove `-printf "%s\n"`, nothing came out. Why was that? Besides, why have they used `xargs -I{} -n1`?

Is there any easier way to find duplicated files?

```
[4a-o07-d1:root/798]#find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1  ./test1.txt
0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1  ./test2.txt
```

Comment: By "quick", do you mean quickest to type, or quickest to finish? If you want the latter, it will pay to partition by file sizes prior to computing and partitioning by MD5 hashes.

Comment: Sorry i think i didn't make it clear. I want to use command line with least complicated to find duplicated files.

Comment: Have a look at jDupes - https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes

Comment: jdupes `-Q` only compares hashes, and `-T` only compares the first block of file data which is extremely fast but risky.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can make it shorter:

```
find . ! -empty -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -w32 -dD
```

Do `md5sum` of found files on the `-exec` action of `find` and then `sort` and do `uniq` to get the files having same the `md5sum` separated by newline.

Comment: Why `-exec sh -c 'md5sum "$1"' _ {} \;` instead of simply `-exec md5sum {} +`?

Comment: @MvG You are absolutely right..edited..while writing the answer i thought from my head that `md5sum` does not take multiple arguments but duh....

Comment: This is not the quickest. For several GB large files, there's no need to hash it whole. You can hash first N kB and then do a full one if same hash is found.

Comment: What does `-dD` mean to `uniq`?

Comment: @Tim I see you've asked a new question already and got the answer :)

Comment: This approach was too slow for me. Took >90 minutes to process >380 GB of JPG and MOV files in a nested directory. Used `ls -lTR` plus the following POSIX awk script to process the same data in 72 seconds: https://github.com/taltman/scripts/blob/master/unix_utils/find-dupes.awk

Comment: @OndraŽižka true, and even faster is to first compare file size without even opening the file.  If only 2 files have the same size, just compare them (cmp) and if more than 2 have the same size, then do checksums.  But why re-invent the wheel, just use one of the other tools that already does that :)

Comment: @TheAmigo, you can't always install tools at will.

Answer (score 88):

You can use [fdupes](http://premium.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html). From `man fdupes`:

> Searches the given path for duplicate files. Such files are found by comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures, followed by a byte-by-byte comparison.

You can call it like `fdupes -r /path/to/dup/directory` and it will print out a list of dupes.

**Update**
You can give it try to [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) also. After setting up fslint, go to `cd /usr/share/fslint/fslint && ./fslint /path/to/directory`

Comment: Not so sure why i was able to install the fdupes on my CentOS 7.
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 ~]# yum install fdupes
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:240:bb8f::1:70: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.vastspace.net/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.vastspace.net/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.

Comment: @TheOne : have you turned on rpmforge repo before running `yum install fdupes` ?

Comment: Seems like there was something wrong with my CentOS. I even couldn't use yum update command.

Comment: @theone that looks like another question. Does it need to be here?

Comment: `fdupes` doesn't consider hardlinks a duplicates, which is great.

Answer (score 40):

In case you want to understand the original command, let's go though that step by step.

```
find -not -empty -type f
```

Find all non-empty files in the current directory or any of its subdirectories.

```
   -printf "%s\n"
```

Print its size. If you drop these arguments, it will print paths instead, breaking subsequent steps.

```
 | sort -rn
```

Sort numerically (`-n`), in reverse order (`-r`). Sorting in ascending order and comparing as strings not numbers should work just as well, though, so you may drop the `-rn` flags.

```
 | uniq -d
```

Look for duplicate consecutive rows and keep only those.

```
 | xargs -I{} -n1
```

For each line of input (i.e. each size that occurs more than once), execute the following command, but replace `{}` by the size. Execute the command once for each line of input, as opposed to passing multiple inputs to a single invocation.

```
   find -type f -size {}c -print0
```

This is the command to run for each size: Find files in the current directory which match that size, given in characters (`c`) or more precisely bytes. Print all the matching file names, separated by null bytes instead of newlines so filenames which contain newlines are treated correctly.

```
 | xargs -0 md5sum
```

For each of these null-separated names, compute the MD5 checksum of said file. This time we allow passing multiple files to a single invocation of `md5sum`.

```
 | sort
```

Sort by checksums, since `uniq` only considers consecutive lines.

```
 | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
```

Find lines which agree in their first 32 bytes (the checksum; after that comes the file name). Print all members of such runs of duplicates, with distinct runs separated by newlines.

Compared to [the simpler command suggested by heemayl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277707/20807), this has the benefit that it will only checksum files which have another file of the same size. It pays for that with repeated `find` invocations, thus traversing the directory tree multiple times. For those reasons, this command is particularly well-suited for directories with few but big files, since in those cases avoiding a checksum call may be more important than avoiding repeated tree traversal.