# What does `-dD` mean to `uniq`?

Tags: coreutils, uniq

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277707/674

```
find . ! -empty -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -w32 -dD
```

can find duplicate files under the current directory.

What does `-dD` mean to `uniq`?
I saw the meanings of `-d` and `-D` in manpage, but not sure what they mean when they are used together. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR** *Bottom line, they do nothing when used together; `-dD` is identical to `-D`.*

#### Research

If you look at the case/switch logic of the `uniq.c` command you can see this first hand:

```
case 'd':
  output_unique = false;
  output_option_used = true;
  break;

case 'D':
  output_unique = false;
  output_later_repeated = true;
  if (optarg == NULL)
    delimit_groups = DM_NONE;
  else
    delimit_groups = XARGMATCH ("--all-repeated", optarg,
                                delimit_method_string,
                                delimit_method_map);
  output_option_used = true;
  break;
```

The way that this code is structured, if either `-dD` is set, `ouput_unique` is set to false; but more importantly, `output_later_repeated` is set to true.

Once that condition is set, `output_later_repeated`, there's no feasible way for `-dD` to have anything but identical output to `-D`.

Incidentally, the [computerhope man page](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuniq.htm) has a better table that explains the `-d` and `-D` switches.

#### References

- [Linux uniq command (computerhope)](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuniq.htm)
- [coreutils/src/uniq.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/uniq.c)

Answer (score 4):

The `uniq -dD` makes no sense - it's equivalent of `uniq -D`. Both `-dD` and `-D` will produce always same result since `-d`'s output set is a subset of `-D`.